# PHP Cron job - no input file specified "SOMETIME"

Tags: php

I have PHP cron job which runs every 30 minutes. PHP cron job is running in Godaddy hosted environment and Godaddy has told that it is not their problem. I run the PHP like this

/web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/html/wp-content/themes/twentyten/totalview.php"

Code inside the totalview.php is

```
<?php
include_once("../../../wp-config.php");
include_once("tplinclude/functions.php");
session_start();

    $res=mysql_query("select sum(`total_num`) from `some_table`");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    echo $row[0] ;
?>
```

But once in a while this will give error message,

---

Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html

No input file specified.

---

Problem is that I get this error only SOMETIME. For example out of 48 execution 8-10 times it will show this error. Rest it will work fine. I pull some data from database, so I know that it works most of the time.

But why it gives error sometime ?

Comment: Add error handling and diagnostics. Do the includes succeed? Does it reach the database successfully? For which URL do you get the 404?

Comment: @triplee. As I have mentioned in the question, it works most of the time.  Which means include succeeds, it reaches database most of the time. It gives error only "sometime". I have put some new diagnostic ...let me see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem faced by customers of godady..

check this..

http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/404-not-found-error-using-cron-job/

Comment: Link rot happens. Please sum up or quote the crucial bits here. Link-only "answers" are subject to deletion. Thanks.

Comment: @rameshd33 This link refers to the issue of passing the arguments properly in cron job. I don't have that issue.

Comment: Anyway I tried the link, but ti does not help. Anyone has any other idea ? I have also tried putting some echo statements inside the script. But when this error happen, nothing get echoed. It means the PHP5 is not able to find the cron script itself sometime.